# Is there no cx_Oracle for Python 3.5 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, cx-oracle, python-3.5

I keep thinking I must surely be missing something.  cx_Oracle seems to be the main Oracle DBAPI for Python, and presumably is still under active development.  And yet there is no download for Python 3.5 (Windows) on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2 -- only versions for Python 2.7 and 3.4 .  The unofficial Windows Python binaries page (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) doesn't even have a section for cx_Oracle.

Am I missing something obvious?  Python 3.5 has been out for several months.  Is there really no binary version of cx_Oracle for Python 3.5 on Windows?

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now. There was a delay as I had to get an environment set up on Windows to compile for Python 3.5. There are no such complications on Linux. :-)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/

Comment: In 5.3 release the windows installer for py3.5 64bit appears to check for 32-bit python (it fails for me saying python3.5-32 is not installed). https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.3 cx_Oracle-5.3-12c.win-amd64-py3.6-2.exe

Comment: I have uploaded new executables that don't appear to have this issue. Please let me know if you still have difficulties with the new executables.